# Is there DB configuration file just for local purpose in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Sails, f.e., there is a `local.js` file which, if filled with configuration for the database, overwrites the default file in which the DB configuration is set. And this `local` file is ignored by GIT, by default, so that when I deploy, the username and password of my local configuration are not revealed or also I don't have to change the default configuration file all the time from local to production username and password.

So, is there something like this in Laravel 4.2, that will override the `app/config/database.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

First of all, Laravel has to determine the current environment using the $app->detectEnvironment(); in the /bootstrap/start.php file.

Once you get it, just create a folder with the environment name which contained files will override the production ones.

For further explaination, just have a look to these two links ( documentation and tutorial ):

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration
http://chrishayes.ca/blog/code/laravel-4-setting-utilizing-environments-environment-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can create `app/config/local/database.php` and if your app's environment is 'local', that will override the global database config file.